# Parsing a file from a database for the date and getting the difference between that date and the current time in Python

Tags: database, python-3.x, parsing, datetime

Trying to extract the "Log_Name" from the database which has the format of "name_year_month_day_hour" and from that I need to parse the year, month, day, and hour then find the difference between that and the current time

```
with open("filename", r):
    for line in filename:
        time = line.split('_')
        year = time[1]
        month = time[2]
        day = time[3]
       hour = time[4]
```

I haven't done this stuff in a really long time. I realize I need to use line.split("_") to parse out the date. But I am not really sure where to go after that

Comment: Database? You are working with a file...

Comment: take a look at this https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html 

mydate = datetime.strptime(last_modified, "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ")

timedelta may help as well.